# oracle plsql error while compiling package spec

Tags: oracle, plsql

```
create or replace
PACKAGE test_pkg 
IS
PROCEDURE abc_requests (p_xys IN NUMBER);                      
end test_pkg;
```

Hello my procedure name is abc_requests with just one parameter.
Below is my error message, please help.

```
Error message:

Error(4,11): PLS-00103: Encountered the symbol " " 
when expecting one of the following:     
 <an identifier> 
 <a double-quoted delimited-identifier>    
 current delete exists prior
```

Answer (score 4):

You have used non-breaking spaces in your statement, instead of plain spaces. If you copy and paste the code from the page as it is displayed above it will work. If you edit the question and copy the *original* code it will not.

You can use the `dump()` function (or a decent text editor) to see what the code actually contains:

```
select dump('PROCEDURE abc_requests (p_xys IN NUMBER);',16) from dual;

DUMP('PROCEDURE ABC_REQUESTS(P_XYS IN NUMBER);',16)                                                                                              
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Typ=96 Len=44: 50,52,4f,43,45,44,55,52,45,c2,a0,61,62,63,5f,72,65,71,75,65,73,74,73,20,28,70,5f,78,79,73,c2,a0,49,4e,c2,a0,4e,55,4d,42,45,52,29,3b
                                          ^^^^^                                                          ^^^^^       ^^^^^
```

I've highlighted the two problem characters, which are the multibye [non-break space](http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/00a0/index.htm) (in UTF-8).

Retype your code, or copy and paste from the question, or just change the non-breaking spaces to normal ones.

Comment: @newbie: As an addendum to this - don't use Word or any other word processing software to create code. Either use something like Notepad or get a decent programmer's editor. These days I use jEdit (whose chief advantage is that it's based on Java and thus can be run on most systems), but there are a ton of such editors out there. Best of luck.

Comment: @alex poole thank you so much for your help. Is there any online free text editor that you are aware of. My problem is still not fixed.

Comment: Why online? As Bob said, use a normal plain text editor; Notepad++, vim, emacs, etc. Where are you running the code? The SQL Developer IDE or Toad or others include text editing. Just don't use Office or other word processors that change what you type. If the problem isn't fixed, retype anything you've previously copied and pasted...